# Need algo for executing tasks sequentially submitted by a particular customer

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, performance

Need high performance algorithm:

Scenario: Tasks are submitted in a thread pool for different customers at very frequent intervals
Requirement: Tasks need to be handle sequentially submitted by a particular customer, but different task submitted by different customer can be executed in parallel.

Comment: In C# it is possible to create a `Dictionary<int, Task>` and then use `ContinueWith`. I can tell you how, if it sounds interesting.

Comment: And what is the question ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how can you write your worker class. The worker class keeps a concurrent map of all the customers being processed currently. Whenever the worker get the next work item off the list, it checks if this customer is currently being processed. If so, It re-enqueues the task at the end of the queue.

Let me know if you have any questions.

```
public class MyWorker extends Thread {
    private static int instance = 0;
    private final Queue<Task> queue;
    // This is used to hold the customer that are in process at this time.
    private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, Boolean> inProcessCustomers;

    public MyWorker(Queue queue, ConcurrentHashMap<String, Boolean> inProcessCustomers) {
        this.queue = queue;
        this.inProcessCustomers = inProcessCustomers
        setName("MyWorker:" + (instance++));
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while ( true ) {
            try {
                Runnable work = null;

                synchronized ( queue ) {
                    while ( queue.isEmpty() )
                        queue.wait();
                    // Get the next work item off of the queue
                    task = queue.remove();
                    // if the customer is in process, then add the task back to the end of the queue and return.
                    if(inProcessCustomers.containsKey(task.getCustomerId()) {
                      queue.add(task);
                      return;
                    }
                    inProcessCustomer.put(task.getCustomerId(), true);
                }

                // Process the work item
                task.run();
                inProcessCustomer.remove(task.getCustomerId());
            }
            catch ( InterruptedException ie ) {
                break;  // Terminate
            }
        }
    }

    private void doWork(Runnable work) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Piyg, I see some problem in your code as you are removing task from queue and then checking for isInProcess and then puts back again that will cause task go end of queue hence order of execution not maintained as there may be other task from same customer in queue, hope you get my point  but main problem is of performance i want to use it in high latency real time solution so it wont work I am looking for some existing algo with performance

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you need a way to map your customer to a queue of tasks.

Assumption: Each customer has a way of being uniquely identified.

I would suggest implementing the [hashCode method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) on whatever object represents your customer.

As the tasks are submitted you create a mapping (using [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)) where the key is your customer and the value is a queue - I suggest [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) - then add either the task or the thread to the queue. As you process tasks remove them (or their thread depending on design choice) from the queue.

EDIT: 
For the purposes of continued discussion I'm going to assume the tasks will be the objects stored in the queue.

Above when I wrote "As you process tasks remove them..." I meant that the task would remain in the queue until completed. You can do this using the [peek](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html#peek()) method of the queue.

Regarding how to process tasks once they are added to the queue the task can be given a reference to the queue object so that once the task is completed it can trigger the next task. The basic algorithm for this piece would go something like this: the controller thread responsible for adding tasks to the queue would check to see if the queue is empty or not. If the queue is not empty it will only add the next task to the queue because the next task is triggered when the current task finishes. If the queue is empty the controller triggers the next task - which it should already have a reference to. When the current task finishes it will call its queue's [poll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html#poll()) method to remove itself from the head of the queue and then calls [peek](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html#peek()) to obtain the next task. The next task is then executed.

Comment: Thanks DB for your answer

Comment: Ohh but one query how will you process the tasks after putting them into queue, can you please explain ?

Comment: The answer doesn't explain the core problem here. That is how to serialize the work based on the customerId.